# How do I disallow saving objects unless its associations are set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to make sure that my `Staff` object cannot save without its `Profile` is created.

Is there any validation I can set to achieve this?

Staff.rb:

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end
```

Profile.rb:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :staff
end
```

Comment: Are you looking for http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated ?

Comment: Validate_associated doesn't enforce presence tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) (it works with this association):

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile

  validates :profile, presence: true
end
```

Or just:

```
validates_presence_of :profile
```

Comment: Do i have to do differently if it is `has_many`? Mind giving an example please?

Comment: @oasisweng, validation will be same as in answer (will means presence at least 1 attribute)